# Создать словарь без переменной

Tags: python

Подскажите, в моем коде вводятся определенные числа строкового вида, которые преобразуются в int через словарь. Есть ли способ убрать переменную для словаря, сослаться на него через литерал? Как это лучше сделать?

```
d = {"one":1, "two":2, "three":3, "four":4, "five":5, "eight":8, "ten":10, "eleven":11, "thirteen":13, "seventeen":17, "nineteen":19}
i = input().split()
l = list(set([d[i] for i in i]))
print(sum([i for i in l if i %2 != 0]))
[print(l[i]*l[i+1]) if i%2==0 else print(l[i]+l[i+1]) for i in range(len(l)-1)]
```

Буду очень признателен за идеи

Comment: что вообще делает этот код? что должно делать ``d[i] for i in i``?

Comment: Здесь нужно посчитать сумму чисел от 0 индекса через один и произведение чисел от 1 индекса через один. For i in i - это попытка свести все к одной переменной. Сама строка просто отбирает числа через множество и возвращает список.

Comment: почему просто не написать `l = list(set([{"one":1, "two":2, "three":3, "four":4, "five":5, "eight":8, "ten":10, "eleven":11, "thirteen":13, "seventeen":17, "nineteen":19}[i] for i in i]))`, если вы так не хотите использовать переменную ?

Comment: Вы правы) Почему-то мне казалось, что это не сработает. Благодарю за идею

Comment: от индекса в каком списке? После set у вас список l имеет мало общего с исходным. Ну и через один это +2, а не +1. Т.е. или вы как-то не так описали задачу, или этот код делает совсем другое

Comment: Простите, видимо, не так объяснил условие, решал через сложение цифр по нечетным индексам и умножение цифр по четным, а по списку двигался через +1 как раз. Может виновата моя кривая реализация

Comment: `[print(l[i]*l[i+1]) if i%2==0 else print(l[i]+l[i+1]) for i in range(len(l)-1)]` - вот так не делайте никогда. Списковое выражение предназначено для формирования списков, а не для печати. Используйте просто обычный цикл for.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто замените

```
l = list(set([d[i] for i in i]))
```

на

```
l = list(set([{"one":1, "two":2, "three":3, "four":4, "five":5, "eight":8, "ten":10, "eleven":11, "thirteen":13, "seventeen":17, "nineteen":19}[i] for i in i]))
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!